Azure Durable function throws out with unknown exception
I have a durable function written in .Net 8.0 Isolated which was running in Windows asp and has recently been switched to Linux asp. However after this switch strangely the function started throwing out with an inexplicable exception after putting all logs at every line. I only get the following.
Microsoft.DurableTask.TaskFailedException: Task 'MergeXmlActivity' (#0) failed with an unhandled exception: Exception while executing function: Functions.MergeXmlActivity ---> DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException: Exception of type 'DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException' was thrown. at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskInternal(String name, String version, String taskList, Type resultType, Object[] parameters) in //src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 121 at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskToWorker[TResult](String name, String version, String taskList, Object[] parameters) in //src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 92 at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTask[TResult](String name, String version, Object[] parameters) in //src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 84 at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options) at Proj.TransformXml.RunOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context) in D:\a\1\s\src\proj\FuncName\TransformXml.cs:line 88 at Proj.DirectFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\src\Proj\obj\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:line 51 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore\src\FunctionsMiddleware\FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.cs:line 38 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.FunctionsOrchestrator.EnsureSynchronousExecution(FunctionContext functionContext, FunctionExecutionDelegate next, FunctionsOrchestrationContext orchestrationContext) in //src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/FunctionsOrchestrator.cs:line 81 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.FunctionsOrchestrator.RunAsync(TaskOrchestrationContext context, Object input) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/FunctionsOrchestrator.cs:line 51
This runs well on local and on azure I have no specific error despite logging with try catch. Does anyone have a clue ?

It looks like the activity function could be failing. Do you have any logging in that?

Yes it's the activity function.i have logs but nothing here to know why

Can you share your complete function code @MandarJogalekar
